# NullPointerException in OnclickListener

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am new in android. In my program I insert a word and its definition and by click the button it inserts the data to database. On click listener I wrote IF for checking if the fields are empty but on Run time even with inserting data it gives the NullPointerException error on OnClick event . I really need some help....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DBAdapter db;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_word);
            EditText def = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_definition);

            if(!String.valueOf(word.getText()).equals("") & 
                    !String.valueOf(def.getText()).equals("")){
                db.insertData(String.valueOf(word.getText()), String.valueOf(def.getText()), 
                         DBAdapter.TABLE_DIC);
            }else{     
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please insert a word and its definition",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    db.close();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    db.open();
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at ir.englishdic.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-23 13:49:45.728: E/AndroidRuntime(15709):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: PLease inittialise and `findViewBy` your Views not in the OnCliCkListener `EditText word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_word);
            EditText def = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_definition);`

Comment: You just have to learn how to read the logcat. It will tell you what's null, and it's often easy to backtrack from there. It's an easy fix 99.99% of the time, and you'll probably never have to post about a NPE here. It might be confusing to find a solution when you're new to java/android, but that's why you read tutorials and code.

Comment: A.S thank you for your response but I did what you say but it didn't work.

Comment: Dear KEYSER : here is my LogCat:

Comment: Dear friends I posted the LogCat just below the code......... :(

Comment: Is there any tutorial for learning LogCat ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `&` in your `if` statement with `&&`.

For example :

```
if(!String.valueOf(word.getText()).equals("") && 
                !String.valueOf(def.getText()).equals(""))
```

Comment: How could this fix a NPE?

Comment: without having logcat, its just a wild guess :)

Comment: The behaviour will not be changed, but I agree the use of `&&` is more appropriate in this case. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your boh EditText global and initialise the in the onCreate not int the onClick and only get the Values in the onClick.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DBAdapter db;   

EditText word, def;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_word);
    def = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_definition);
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                         

            if(!String.valueOf(word.getText()).equals("") && 
                    !String.valueOf(def.getText()).equals("")){
                db.insertData(String.valueOf(word.getText()), String.valueOf(def.getText()), 
                         DBAdapter.TABLE_DIC);
            }else{     
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please insert a word and its definition",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How could this fix a NPE?